# Send structure with dynamically allocated arrays in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I would like an opinion on a situation in which I find myself in my project. i basically have a structure composed of an int, an array of ints and an array of chars. I need to send this structure to another process. the problem is that these two arrays in the structure are dynamically allocated (practically they are pointers). What's the best way to do this?

I have two main ideas:

1. Use Pack and Unpack but this is very heavy (this sends in repeat often).
2. Concatene all three data in one single array and send it with a simple send.
3. Use MPI_Type_struct but I don't know the specific size of this arrays (it change often in all send).

Someone can help me please. I don't upload code because is very complex and long.

Comment: if the performance issue is critical and this is applicable, allocate your data with a single `malloc()` and have the second and third members of your `struct` point into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of those three options Pack/Unpack is probably the best choice. (2) is basically what Pack/Unpack does. MPI_Type_struct won't work if elements inside the struct are dynamically allocated.

Another option is to simply send the arrays in separate messages. Avoids the extra buffer and the packing/unpacking but of course sends more messages, so it may be better or worse performance-wise. If the arrays are very small, it will probably be worse, otherwise it might not make much of a difference or even be faster. Try it out and measure what's best.